# jQuery DataTable repopulate table from search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a function that populates the DataTable when the document is ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "ajax": 'api/qnams_all.php',
   "dataType": "json",  
   "bDestroy": true,
   "stateSave": true
   });

   // this portion reloads the datatable without refreshing the page
   setInterval(function() {
     $dataTable.ajax.reload();
   }, 60000);
 }
```

So now I want to add a search feature.  It would basically re-populate the DataTable with the search data returned from the server.

Directly below is the jQuery that retrieves the parameters entered by the user:

```
 $('#searchSubmit').on('click', function()
 {
   var searchbooking = $('#searchbooking').val();
   var searchquote = $('#searchquote').val();

   $.ajax({
     url:'api/qnams_all.php',
     type:"POST",
     data:{searchbooking: searchbooking, searchquote: searchquote},
     contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     dataType:"json"
   }).done(function(response){
      console.log(response.data)
   }).fail(function(){
      alert('error');
   }).always(function(){
      alert('done');
   });
 });
```

Here is the PHP process found in api/qnams_all.php:

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database.php");
   include("../include/sessions.php");

   $_SESSION['where'] = "";
   $searchbooking = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(strtoupper($_POST['searchbooking']))));
   $searchquote = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(strtoupper($_POST['searchquote'])))); 

   // build the WHERE clause
   if($searchbooking != ""){
     $_SESSION['where'] = "booking = '".$searchbooking."'";
   }
   if($searchquote != ""){
     if( $_SESSION['where'] != "" ) 
     $_SESSION['where'] .= " AND ";$_SESSION['where'] .= "quote = '".$searchquote."'";
   }

   // check if WHERE is blank
   if($_SESSION['where'] == ""){$where = "where TLI_COMPLETE = 'N'";}
   else{$where = $_SESSION['where'];}

   // run the query
   $select = "SELECT 
                CONCAT('\"',COALESCE(booking,''),'\"')
                ,CONCAT('\"',COALESCE(quote,''),'\"')
              FROM
                searchTable " . $where . "";

   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error());
   $resnum = mysqli_num_rows($query);   

   echo "{\"data\":[";
   $i = 1;  
   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
   {
     echo "[";
       echo implode(', ', $row);
     echo "]";
     if($i < $resnum){
       echo ",";
     }
     $i++;
   }
 }
 echo "]}";
 mysqli_free_result($query);    
 ?>
```

The PHP process above works perfectly with the `$(document).ready()` function.

My question is: how can I manipulate my code so that the search functions works with the `ready()` function?

Right now, the search function is located outside of the `ready()` function.  Can I apply the search function within the `ready()` function?  If so, how would the AJAX call look like?

Currently, it reads:

```
 "ajax": 'api/qnams_all.php'
```

If I am able to add the search to the `ready()` function, would this AJAX call change?

To put it in one question, how can I add the search feature to the `ready()` function so that I can initially display data, and then repopulate the data if the user decides to search for a record?

Comment: I would recommend you look into the columns(x).search() function, you can perform live search on columns in your initial data without needing to recall the api

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep 2 copies of the same code(ajax part)

1. In `document.ready` with `async:false` in `ajax` call.(Will load the search results when the page opens).
2. The original place where it is now i.e inside the `onClick function`.(For the default behaviour).

That's because you need to wrap your ajax call in an eventListener and here you are having to separate events.